# Get label value form another metric base on other common value in PromQL

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have two metrics that I want to use `app` value from metric2 as title of grafana chart of metric1 base on compare of `process_id` value from metric1 and `pid` value from metric2.

```
metric1{process_id="10080",mode="privileged"}

metric2{pid="10080",app="AppName"}
```